# c# mvc how to call modelpopup using @ajax.actionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here i'm trying to using ajax call Without refreshing my page but call modelpopup
for that i wrorte

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("CheckOut", "EditMasterDatadetails", "Home", new { Id = _objMaster.Id },
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    //InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
    UpdateTargetId = "myModal",
    OnBegin = "OpenEditDialog()"
    //OnComplete = "ShowPopup",
    //OnSuccess = "showModal"//"showModal"

}, new {
    @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg",
    @id = "chkOut"
})
```

MY Jquery code is

```
function  OpenEditDialog(){
$('#MyModel').modal('show');
}
```

But When i click on Link Even my code is not Reaching upto fun

Answer (score 1):

You can `ng-repeat` over an array or an object, not a function that returns nothing (undefined).

Your controller needs to prepare an accessible array

```
$scope.YearList = [];
for (var Y = 1991; Y <= 1995; Y++) {
    $scope.YearList.push(Y);
}
```

and the ng-repeat goes over that `YearList`

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option ng-repeat="Year in YearList" value="{{Year}}">{{Year}}</option>
</select>
```